# Jquery selector when attribute data is not empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having this next issue.
I am developing a calendar with date formats and therefore what I need at this point is to be able to select all elements which their data attribute is not empty, in this case the na me of the attribute is `data-hueco`.

```
<p class="huecoDisponible" data-centro="HVA" data-hueco="0000000367#20201120#161000" style="cursor:pointer;">16:10</p>
```

I already tried certain things such as:

```
if(!$('.huecoDisponible').is(":empty")){
   console.log(!$('.huecoDisponible').is(":empty"));
}
```

This approach obviously is not working.
I also have tried another option which is:

```
console.log($('.huecoDisponible').attr(':not([data-hueco=""])'));
console.log($('.huecoDisponible:not([data-hueco=""])');
```

In this case I am not quite sure if the selection is being done appropiately.
Finally, to give you one more hint is that I am creating all of these paragraphs by this next function which is called inside an AJAX method. Inside there I am creating the html elements by appending them to 7 different id's which present every day of the week.
Every `p` element has two `data-attributes`.

```
              function filtrarPintarNuevoHueco(result, week){
                html = '';
                for (var b = 0; b < 7; b++ ) {
                    var diaFiltro = $('#'+arr[b]).attr("data-date");
                    let toto = result.citas.filter(c => c.fecha == diaFiltro);
                    for(var i = 0; i < toto.length; i++) {
                        let nuevoHueco = toto[i].fecha;
                        let codigoCita = toto[i].numcita;
                        let nuevoHuecoHora = toto[i].hora;
                        var hour = nuevoHuecoHora.substring(0, 2);
                        var min = nuevoHuecoHora.substring(2, 4);
                        let codigoCentro = toto[i].centro;
                        let nuevoHuecoHoraFormatted = hour + ':' + min;
                        html = '<p class="huecoDisponible" data-centro="' + codigoCentro + '"  data-hueco="'+ codigoCita+ '" style="cursor:pointer;">'+ nuevoHuecoHoraFormatted+"</p>" ;
                        $("#" + arr[b] +' div').append(html);
                    }
                }

                $('.huecoDisponible').on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $('.huecoDisponible').removeClass("huecoDisponible_active");
                    $(this).addClass("huecoDisponible_active");
                    let dataHueco = $(this).attr("data-hueco");
                    let dataCentro = $(this).attr("data-centro");
                    let diaNombre = $(this).parent().parent().find("h3")[0].textContent;
                    let diaFecha =  $(this).parent().parent().find("h4")[0].textContent;
                    let horaCita = $(this).attr("data-hueco").split("#")[2];
                    let hora = horaCita.substring(0,2);
                    let min = horaCita.substring(2,4);
                    let horaFormatted = hora + ":" + min;
                    reservarCitaMasHuecos(dataHueco, dataCentro, diaNombre, diaFecha, horaFormatted);
                });
            }



  const devolverHuecosSemana = (especialista, diaSapLunes) => {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.ActionLink("HuecosLibres", "HandlerEntityDbHub")',
                type: "POST",
                data: {"modo":"", "centro":"", "medico": especialista.idEspecialista, "fecha": diaSapLunes }
            }).done(function (result, status, xhr) {
                //tenemos que comprobar que estamos en el especialista que corresponde
                 
                if (result == undefined) {
                    alert("Este médico no tiene huecos");
                } else {
                    result = JSON.parse(result);
                    if(result.citas.length > 0){
                        filtrarPintarNuevoHueco(result, diasSemana.week); // IT IS CALLED INSIDE HERE, PRINTS THE APPOINTMENT FOR A CERTAIN DAY OF THE WEEK
                    }else{
                        alert("Este médico no tiene huecos");
                    }
                }
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Este médico no tiene huecos");
            });
        }
```

If anyone can give me some advice on how to proceed with the rest, it would be really appreciating.
Thanks you

Comment: Hi , you are checking data-attr value inside this handler i.e : `$('.huecoDisponible').on('click', function(e){..`  ? Also , did you tried like this : `console.log($(".huecoDisponible").attr('data-hueco') != "")` ?

Comment: I am checking it inside the handler but actually, I do the check after the whole html elements have been generated with the .`attr('data-hueco')` . I will post my answer tomorrow as I already found where the problem was.  Thanks for the hint!